# JOptionPane input validation with if else statement

Tags: java, swing, validation, input, joptionpane

I wanted to when user inputs a number that's not positive integer up to 100 it'll show an error message and the user will input again if input is right then proceed to the if/else statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Culminating {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner  in = new Scanner (System.in);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME");
        String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("KINDLY ENTER YOUR GRADES");
       int num = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
      
       
       if (num>100)
     {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: PLEASE ENTER UP TO 100 ONLY" ); 
    
     }  
       
       else if (num>93)
     {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " A " + "\n\nPoints: " + 4.0 ); 
     }  
       
    else if (num > 90 )
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " +" A- " + "\n\nPoints: " + 3.7 ); 
    }
    
    else if (num> 87){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " B+ " + "\n\nPoints: " + 3.3 ); 
    }
       
    else if (num> 83){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " B " + "\n\nPoints: " + 3.0 ); 
    }
       
    else if (num>80){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " B- " + "\n\nPoints: " + 2.7 ); 
    }
       
    else if (num>77){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " C+ " + "\n\nPoints: " + 2.3 ); 
    }
    
    else if (num>73){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " C " + "\n\nPoints: " + 2.0 ); 
    }
       
    else if (num> 70){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " C- " + "\n\nPoints: " + 1.7 ); 
    }
    
    else if (num> 67){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " D+ " + "\n\nPoints: " + 1.3 ); 
    }
    
    else if (num>64){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " D " + "\n\nPoints: " + 1.0 ); 
    }
    
    else if (num<64){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Letter Grade: " + " E " + "\n\nPoints: " + 0.0 ); 
    } 
       }
}
```

Comment: I'll be very thankful for the help.

Comment: `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,100,1))` <- the result from that spinner will *always* be valid. Also the user will thank you.